# How to show more post at a given category?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I need to show more post at the category `state` (with `tag_ID=21`), for example, I set the number of post show at homepage is 6, but I want 10 post when archive `state`, is there any way to add a filter in `functions.php`?

Maybe `posts_per_page` and `wp count posts` is helpful.

---Edit---

My Code in `functions.php` is:

```
function change_numberposts( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query
    if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        // Category 21
        if ( $query->is_category( array( 21, 'shuoshuo', '说说' )  ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        } else {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );     
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_numberposts' );
```

I also tried

```
is_category( 21 )
is_category('21')
is_category('shuoshuo')
```

The only work case is

```
is_category()
```

which will output 10 posts in each category.

I also noted that `is_category( 21 )` is work for the permalinks set to be numeric. Since my permalinks is self-defined: `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%.html`, how to make the above code behaved as expected?

Answer (score 7):

put this code in `functions.php` :

```
function change_numberposts( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query
    if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        // Home page
        if ( $query->is_home() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
        }
        // Category 21
        if ( $query->is_category( 21 ) ) { // parameter for is_category may be Category ID, Category Title, Category Slug or Array of IDs, names, and slugs.
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_numberposts' );
```

**Links:**

[is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Comment: You should put all conditional logic inside the callback, for clarity.

Comment: I see what you mean. I usually put the conditionnal before calling the function, but your way allow to add further rules later more easily. Thanks for editing, Chip Bennett.

Comment: Also: the query conditionals won't likely be available at `plugins_loaded`, which is when your `add_action()` conditional wrapper would fire by default.

Comment: That almost work, but since my permalinks set to: `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%.html`, which is not work, why?

Comment: Don't know, how does it does not work ? What's happening ?

Comment: @ChipBennett : So the conditionnal logic *must* be in the function and not the call. Thanks.

Comment: `%postname%` would be a *single post*, and not a *category archive index* page.

Comment: This is another question. Does the change of number of posts is working ?

Comment: If I don't set `21` for the `is_category()`, then it will work, but for all category, it will output `10` posts. If I set `21` as `is_category(21)`, then it only work for the numeric  permalinks.

Comment: Meaning that with `is_category(21)` : you have 10 posts, but the permalinks are wrong ? Or that you don't have 10 posts, but 6 - and that you have 10 only if you remove the pretty rewriting of permalinks ?

Comment: ah, my god! When I have self-defined permalinks, it shall be work when I use `is_category()`, and of course, output 10 post; But in case if I want only the category 21 should output 10 post others be 6, then `is_category( 21 )` is only worked for numeric permalinks, did I make myself clear?

Comment: Did you try `is_category( '21' )` or `is_category( 'trace' ) ?

Comment: @simon yes, I tried `is_category('21')` and `is_category('shuoshuo')`, since the category 21 can be reached by `/category/shuoshuo`. They are not solve the problem I described in the later case.

Comment: Try to change permalink rewrite with `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%` and see what happens. Otherwise, send code displaying categories.

Comment: The category id, `21` in this case, will always match regardless of the permalink structure. Are you sure you are loading the category 21 page?

Comment: @CharlesClarkson not as you said in my case!

Comment: @vanabel code updated, please change `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' )` to `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 )`, second param for `posts_per_page` must be a numeric, I think this is why it's not working

Comment: @Ravs It is not work!

Comment: Something is happening that we cannot see and that you cannot identify. [Edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/124669/edit) with the everything that is in your functions.php theme file. To add the code you will have to indent each line 4 spaces before pasting it. Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have a page or a post with the same name as your category ?